# LAN Segment vs. Internal Network

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

As part of a class project, I am setting up on VirtualBox an Endian Firewall to work with a Windows 7 Virtual Machine on a Mac OS X Mavericks host. My class project actually uses a different OS for the host and a different virtual machine.

My question is very simple: is the "Internal Network" choice in VirtualBox the equivalent of the VMPlayer "LAN segment" option of the Network Adapter? If not, how do I set up LAN segments on VirtualBox running on Mac OS X?

PS: I am aware that this question is a bit related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338256/how-do-i-access-my-ubuntu-10-04-virtualboxs-localhost-from-my-host-machine-mac/9346282#9346282) in the community.

Answer (score 1):

Although this does not solve my problem, at least I consider the following an answer to my question:

> "This makes sense from a security perspective to have as a default."
>   -- If you want to create isolated networks, that's what internal network (in VirtualBox) or LAN segment (in VMware Player) is for.

Found it as a comment on a discussion on [xmodulodotcom](http://xmodulo.com/2013/04/vmware-player-vs-virtualbox-feature-comparison.html)

I'll note also that the above that comment is full of good info as to the difference between virtualbox and vmplayer.